# How to disable Super+{N} shortcuts in Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I've recently upgraded my Linux Mint to 19.3 (Cinnamon 4.4.8) and it installed Super+Number shortcut for starting apps from panel.
When I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in launches File Manger, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> — terminal etc.

I'm not sure but I've somehow disabled this behaviour in previous version, but now I can not find any preferences related to it.

Those shortcuts are breaking my Terminal shortcut where Super+Number is supposed to switch between tabs in Terminal. This is really annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable Super+{Number} opening programs that are pinned to your panel:

- Open Start Menu >> 'Applets'
- Under 'Manage' look for 'Grouped Window List' and click on the gear icon to configure
- Under 'General' >> 'Hot Keys' toggle the option 'Enable Super+ shortcut to switch/open apps'

This works as of Linux Mint 20 and Cinnamon 4.6.7

Comment: It wasn't working in Mint 19.3 but is working in Mint 20. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, those hotkeys are hardcoded in the `grouped-window-list` applet.
To fix the behaviour, one should edit the file 
`/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/grouped-window-list@cinnamon.org/applet.js`
There is lines:

```
bindAppKey(i) {
    Main.keybindingManager.addHotKey('launch-app-key-' + i, '<Super>' + i, () => this.onAppKeyPress(i));
    Main.keybindingManager.addHotKey('launch-new-app-key-' + i, '<Super><Shift>' + i, () =>
        this.onNewAppKeyPress(i)
    );
}
```

You can edit hotkeys or completely remove them by voiding the method body or commenting out method call in `bindAppKeys` method.

This should be done after each update unfortunatenly.

Comment: As an easier approach, one may comment out `this.bindKeys()` line in `on_applet_added_to_panel` method to avoid any hotkey binding.